# Error when migrating from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I use `Realm` in my project and so far it has been great ! I have migrated from `swift 1.2` to `Swift 2` and now I have an error when compiling my code on the *device* (not on simulator).

Here is the error :

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/64E2D461-F95C-4E86-B3D3-5FAAA00AF77C/myPhotoCalendar.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
>   Reason: image not found

I really don't understand what it means. I tried some tricks but none of them worked so far. Any one could help me ?

Comment: Can you ensure in your Xcode project you have correctly embedded  Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework ?  Check your build phases>embedded frameworks.

Comment: Actually, I just update the Realm Framework with cocoapod like it's written on realm documentation. But indeed, it seems that embeded frameworks is empty. How can I do to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error, because you're using dynamic frameworks, but they are not copied into your app bundle. On the simulator, the dynamic linker can still find the built framework in the build products directory. But this is not present in the sandbox of the device, where your app is executed.

It seems like that's the case because the build phase "Embed Pods Frameworks" is missing from your project. Please make sure that CocoaPods is up to date. (`gem update cocoapods`) You might then want to use your integration by [`pod deintegrate`](https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) and re-install from scratch again. (Alternatively, you could remove the aggregate target `Pods_*.framework` from the linked libraries.) That should make sure, that all build phases are re-created by CocoaPods.

For references, you should have the build phases like seen below in your project's target:

[image: build phases in Xcode]

The mentioned aggregate target framework is seen in the "Link Binary With Libraries" pane as `Pods.framework` here. The name depends on whether or not you integrate multiple targets of your project and how they are named. So it could be also named `Pods_YourApp.framework`.

Comment: Hello Marius,
Thanks a lot for your support but unfortunatly after having followed your answer, try and try again I have the same error.
Perhaps it's because I don't realy understand this sentence in your answer :
" (Alternatively, you could remove the aggregate target Pods_*.framework from the linked libraries.) That should make sure, that all build phases are re-created by CocoaPods."

What is the agregate target pods_*.framework from the linked libraries and how to remove ?


Could you help me ?

Thks again
Vincent.

Comment: I added a screenshot and a bit more explanation what I mean by aggregate target to my answer. Please let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Hello Marius, I redo all your the instructions (pod deintegrate... pod install..). I reopen my project check the "Link with binaries with library" and "Embeded pods framework" (they are both ok) and try to launch my app but still the error "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E77DC716-808A-460F-93CD-049597FDFFF8/myPhotoCalendar.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
  Reason: image not found"

Comment: Hello @marius I succed to resolve the problem by following exactly your process but doing a $pod update after de $pod deintegrate and NOT a $pod install.... do you know why ?

Comment: @Zipette: That's great to hear. I was quite puzzled why it was not working for you and I'm honestly surprised by that as a solution. You might have just circumvented a faulty cache in that way. Thanks for sharing what you have figured out.